# Trying to Concatenate from another sheet on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VB and am trying to get a code together that will pull data from two cells (B13,B14) onto Sheet3, while having the concatenate and data in the next empty cell on table (A3:A47) onto Sheet10.

This is the input:

```
 #   A    B
 #1
 #2
 #3
 .
 .
 .
 #13     02
 #14     01
```

And desired output (some characters are added to the string):

```
 #   A           B
 #1
 #2
 #3  not-empty
 #4  not-empty
 #5  not-empty
 #6  not-empty
 #7  R02-S01
 #8
 ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by concatenate? Please show desired output.

Comment: B13 = 02
B14 = 01

Desired output is R02-S01

Now, I understand how to add in the extra characters, but I am running into trouble when it comes to extracting the values and adding them to a string. I am further struggling with figuring out how to transfer the data across to other sheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This macro does what you want (or at least what you mentioned). You can loop this over a range for further use.

```
 Option Explicit

 Dim iwsh As Worksheet
 Dim owsh As Worksheet
 Dim output As String
 Dim i As Integer

 Sub Copy()

 Set iwsh = Worksheets("Sheet3")
 Set owsh = Worksheets("Sheet10")

 i = 3

 While owsh.Cells(i, 1) <> ""

 i = i + 1

 Wend

 output = "R" & iwsh.Cells(13, 2).Value & "-S" & iwsh.Cells(14, 2).Value

 owsh.Cells(i, 1) = output

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! However, I am getting a Compile Error: Variable not defined. The highlighted error is on i = 3

Comment: Ah, I see now. I am trying to assign it to a command button. I thought by changing sub copy () to the button name, that it would work. So there seems to be a disconnect.

Comment: @Thelnternet Try now. You need to declare `i` (or any other variable) as we are going with `Option Explicit`.

Comment: @Thelnternet For assigning purposes, right-click on the button and click on `Assign Maco...`

Comment: New error: Run-time error '9': subscript out of range.      Edit:problem solved thanks so much for your patience and help!

Comment: @Thelnternet That's `subscript out of range` error. Make sure name of the sheets are correct in the vba according to your workbook. Make sure you are adding the code to the right workbook (i.e. the one that has the data in those sheets). Also, make sure that you are in that workbook when you are running the code. Meaning, it should be active.